# How to verify ECDSA with Public Key?

Tags: android, android-keystore, ecdsa

I have the following methods for generating keys and signing the password message.

```
public void generateKeys() {
try {
  keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_NAME);
  keyStore.load(null);

  if (!keyStore.containsAlias(KEY_NAME)) {
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_EC, KEYSTORE_NAME);
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(
        new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
            .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"))
            // Require the user to authenticate with a fingerprint to authorize
            // every use of the private key
            .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
            .build());
    keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
  }

  loadKeys();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (CertificateException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (KeyStoreException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

```
public BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject getCryptoObject() {
cryptoObject = new BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(signature);
return cryptoObject;
}

private void loadKeys() {
try {
  keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_NAME);
  keyStore.load(null);
  if (keyStore.containsAlias(KEY_NAME)) {
    publicKey = keyStore.getCertificate(KEY_NAME).getPublicKey();
    privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);
    signature = Signature.getInstance(Constants.SIGNATURE);
    signature.initSign(privateKey);
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (CertificateException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (KeyStoreException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public String sign(String inputStr) {
try {
  Signature signature = cryptoObject.getSignature();
  signature.update(inputStr.getBytes());
  byte[] signedBytes = signature.sign();
  String result = HexManager.bytesToHex(signedBytes);
  Log.d("TAG", result);
  return result;
} catch (SignatureException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

}

After that, I saved the signed password in Shared Preferences. Later, I want to verify the saved password with a new password that is verified with the fingerprint.

Here is my method to verify:

```
public boolean verify(String inputStr, String savedStr) {
try {
  Signature signature = cryptoObject.getSignature();
  signature.initVerify(publicKey);
  signature.update(inputStr.getBytes());
  boolean isVerified = signature.verify(savedStr.getBytes());
  return isVerified;
} catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SignatureException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return false;
}
```

But it always return false.

Does anybody knows why?

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you be undoing the `bytesToHex` step at some point during the signature verification process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in your `sign()` method you're returning the `Hex` of the `byte[]` obtained from the `signature.sign()` method. If this is what you're saving as `savedStr`. Then the verification method should be changed to convert the `Hex` encoded string to a `byte[]`. You could use `HexManager.hexToBytes()` (or equivalent) if it exists to convert the `savedStr` to a `byte[] savedStrBytes`.

```
public boolean verify(String inputStr, String savedStr) {
    try {
        byte[] savedStrBytes = HexManager.hexToByes(savedStr);
        Signature signature = cryptoObject.getSignature();
        signature.initVerify(publicKey);
        signature.update(inputStr.getBytes());
        boolean isVerified = signature.verify(savedStrBytes);
        return isVerified;
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```